# Issues with dropdown list not displaying properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

On my own computer the dropdown list here displays the top option and then the selected option in formatted text within the top bar. However on every other display (mobile, computers which aren't mine), the dropdown menu appears to be blank.

Does anyone know if there is anything HTML or CSS (or Javascript) that could be used to make sure it displays correctly on all websites? For example, if I clicked `Newsletter`, then `Newsletter` is displayed in that top bar. The functionality is fine, visibility isn't.

```
<select class="longdropdown">
    <option>Choose an action</option>
    <option>Sign up to our Newsletter!</option>
    <option>Submit a comment or query</option>
    <option>Submit a suggestion</option>
</select>
```

I have played around with `value` and `label` attributes but it doesn't make a difference. I'm unsure why I named it with a class as there is no CSS attached to that either (before anyone asks!).

[image]

Comment: What plugin or styling options are you using on that `select`, as it's not a standard one.

Comment: I used some CSS formatting on the height of the form, but otherwise it is bare html. There is an change() JQuery command when the option is selected or changed - but the issue happens even without it.

Comment: That is 100% not a bare HTML select element. If you check the element via the DOM inspector you will be able to find what CSS is applied to it and where it's coming from

Answer (score 0):

Try using a value option

```
<select class="longdropdown">
  <option value="Choose an action">Choose an action</option>
  <option value="Sign up to our Newsletter!">Sign up to our Newsletter!</option>
  <option value="Submit a comment or query">Submit a comment or query</option>
  <option value="Submit a suggestion">Submit a suggestion</option>
</select>
```